# Why does CUBLAS use const pointers for parameters?

Tags: pointers, cuda, constants, gpgpu, cublas

e.g.,

```
cublasStatus_t cublasSgemm(cublasHandle_t handle,
                       cublasOperation_t transa, cublasOperation_t transb,
                       int m, int n, int k,
                       const float           *alpha,
                       const float           *A, int lda,
                       const float           *B, int ldb,
                       const float           *beta,
                       float           *C, int ldc)
```

This relates to a number of points of confusion:

- What does the `const` achieve?
- Why do we have to provide pointers even for scalar parameters?
- What does this have to do with `CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_HOST`?
- Do we need to explicitly create temporary `const` variables to pass them, or will a normal pointer do?

[CUBLAS library](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_8_1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `const` denotes *input* arguments as read only both to the caller, and to the compiler (which can have an effect on optimisation)
2. Because using a pointer, as opposed to a value, allows CUBLAS v2 routines to read from either host or device memory (this is different from the CUBLAS v1 API)
3. See above. It is now possible for CUBLAS v2 calls to read scalar parameters from GPU memory, meaning that intermediate memory transfers from host to device can be eliminated and the performance of some types of operations improved. `CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_HOST` one of the two possible pointer modes which the CUBLAS v2 API can use, the other being `CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_DEVICE`. `cublasSetPointerMode` can be used to control the pointer behaviour of the v2 API, defining where numerical input and return values are in written to host or device memory.
4. No. It is legal to implicitly cast to `const` in C, but not legal to cast constness away. C++ provides the `const_cast` casting mechanism for this.

Answer (score 2):

In the example above the `const` pointers are all *input* parameters that will not be modified by the function. You don't need to pass actual pointers to const here - the const qualifier just guarantees that the data you provide for input will not be written to.

The non-const `C` parameter is an *output* parameter which points to data which will be modified by the function.

I don't know why `alpha` and `beta` are passed as pointers - this may just be a legacy of BLAS's FORTRAN origins.

Comment: On the last point, it is so that parameters can be read from device memory without intermediate copies, between host and device and so that L1 BLAS routines can leave results in device memory, rather than requiring a redundant device->host->device copy cycle

Answer (score 1):

As to your 4th question, talonmies is correct, you need to cast to a const.  A good example of how to cast to const for cublas< t>gemmBatched is given in the CUDA samples: batchCUBLAS.

They give this line for example:

```
 status1 = cublasXgemmBatched(handle, params.transa, params.transb, params.m, params.n,
                                     params.k, &params.alpha, (const T_ELEM **) devPtrA_dev, rowsA,
                                     (const T_ELEM **) devPtrB_dev, rowsB, &params.beta, devPtrC_dev, rowsC, opts.N);
```

where in the CUDA example, T_ELEM is a float.  Notice the 8th input:

```
(const T_ELEM **) devPtrA_dev
```

which casts to a const.  devPtrA was set in CUDA memory in the usual way, which also can be found in this CUDA sample.

You can find more information about CUDA samples here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-code-samples